# How do I update nuget files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, nuget, updates

Im creating a webform aspx site. I have updated Bootstrap from 3.7.7 to 4.3.1 with Nuget manager. It took over a day before the new bootstrap files was added to debug.

Now I like to go back again, so I choose version 3.7.7 from Nuget again, and all files in Visual studio show correct. But when I run the debug the source files are linked to 4.3.1.

Can I force the changes to take effect? So I dont have to wait.

Comment: Look for your reference to bootstrap within the code, make sure the paths are correct.

Comment: "It took over a day before the new bootstrap files was added to debug." what do you mean by this ?

Comment: Since it's a webforms project, you're probably using nuget packages with `packages.config`. In this case, NuGet will change the contents of your project when you install a different version of the package. If you use source control, you should see the files changed. If you don't see the changes in your browser, it's probably a deployment or caching issue.

Comment: Hi, how did you know the source file are linking to the 4.3.1 during the debugging process? Could you please share more detail information about how to reproduce this issue, that will help us analysis, thanks.

Comment: There was some visual studio cache that needed to be clear.